# Is the Freebase JSON API still alive?

Tags: api, freebase

anyone know if developing against Freebase JSON API will be a waste of time.

It seems to have been absorbed into Google but they love killing off APIs just when you get into them

Still a huge DB online:

www.freebase.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Freebase APIs](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API) are still very much alive. We just recently re-released our read API services to run on Google's API infrastructure and we have several more API services in the works. Please rest assured that there are no plans to "kill off" the Freebase APIs.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't be a waste of time, as long you base your work on the new [Google-based APIs](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread) rather than the [old ones](https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?help) (unless you have an immediate need for functionality that hasn't been ported yet (e.g. writes) and understand the limited nature of the development you're investing in).

If you're familiar with the old APIs (or are following tutorials of uncertain vintage which may be based on them), be sure to review the list of [changes](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API_Changes).  Some functionality (e.g. geosearch) is being retired and there are significant changes to some of the ancilliary APIs like search.